# Cannot Convert String to Int from BLE Data

Tags: ios, swift

I've spent 3 weeks avoiding this question on Stackover flow but I'm at my wits end.

I don't know why I can create a string manually and convert it into an INT but can't do the same thing from BLE data.

This is my code:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR ON UPDATING VALUE FOR CHARACTERISTIC: \(characteristic) - \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            return
        }
        
        
        guard let data = characteristic.value else{
            return
        }
        
      //  let myString = "345345" // I CAN MANUALLY SET A STRING
        
      //  let myInt = Int(myString) ?? 2
       // print (myInt + 523436) I CAN CONVERT AND USE THIS INT
        
      
        
        let weightStringData = swiftDataToString(ESP32Data: data)
        
        func swiftDataToString(ESP32Data:Data) -> String? {
            return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        
       
        if let myNewstring = weightStringData{
            
          //  print(myNewstring) // THIS PRINTS AS A STRING
            
            let myInt = Int(myNewstring) ?? 2 //THIS DOES NOTHING IT SEEMS OTHER THAN SET THE CONSTANT TO "2"

          print (myInt + 9898) //CANT USE THE INT LIKE IN THE ABOVE MANUAL EXAMPLE
            
   
            
        }else{
               print("Nothing")
           }
       
        
        
        
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are dealing with a `String`? To check, can you try this: `print("'\(myNewstring)' of type '\(type(of: myNewstring))'")`

Comment: P.S, why are you declaring the `func swiftDataToString(...)` inside your
 `func peripheral(...)`, why not just do:
 `if let myNewstring = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){...}`

Comment: working dog : so this is strange, when using the entire print function above I just get a series of numbers without the type of. When I omit the first half and just leave of type '\(type(of: myNewstring))'") I get a result of "String".

Comment: Post the actual output of printing `myNewString` into your question.

Comment: OUTPUT print("'\(myNewstring)' of type '\(type(of: myNewstring))'")'392814'392859'392859'392859'392859'392929'392959'392939'392931'392950'392956'392987'392963'392876'392903'392896'392891'392893'392826'392824'392838'392847'392902'392953'392910'392838'392878'392846'392927'392903'392830'392861'392806'392864'392910'392921'392908'392889'392864'392898'392983'393003'392969'392955'392919'392960'392929

Comment: That explains why you can't convert it into an `Int`.

Comment: its a string but it seems like its a constant stream of characters and there is no end? it results as a string if I omit print("'\(myNewstring)'

Comment: have you tried a different encoding, e.g. `String(data: data, encoding: .utf16)`. What are you expecting the stream of characters to be?

Comment: the stream of characters is correct, the data coming from the BLE device is ascii . so the data value from the characteristic.value is something like 51, 57 ,50, 56, 57, 51 which is what I expect

Comment: It just seems like the compiler ant identify the EOL (end of line)?